# How can I get the current refinement *count* using Algolia?

Tags: reactjs, algolia, react-instantsearch

[React InstantSearch](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/) provides a `CurrentRefinements` component which gives the currently selected refinements.

But all I want is to get the number of filters (refinements) being applied. I feel like this should be really easy but have been banging my head for the past 4 hours trying to figure it out.

Edit: You can see a working example with `<CurrentRefinements>` [here](https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/storybook/?selectedKind=CurrentRefinements&selectedStory=with%20RefinementList&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=1&addonPanel=kadira%2Fjsx%2Fpanel)

But again, my goal isn't to list the current refinements, it's to get a count of the number of refinements being applied in total.

Comment: Please provide some sample code

Comment: @SoluableNonagon added a link to some example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working using one of the connectors they provide. Here's the solution:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {connectCurrentRefinements} from 'react-instantsearch/connectors'

class RefinementCount extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>filtered: {this.props.items.length}</h1>
    )
  }
}

export default connectCurrentRefinements(RefinementCount)
```

Relevants docs: https://community.algolia.com/react-instantsearch/connectors/connectCurrentRefinements.html

Answer (score 0):

For Vue instantSearch, you can simply slot in the `items` like this below so I would think React has something equivalent, hopefully without having to use a connector.

```
<ais-current-refinements>
 <template v-slot="{ items }">
  <p>{{ items.length }}</p>
 </template>
</ais-current-refinements>
```